Can I use my phone or MacBook to replicate my home wifi for on the road SSH access?
So I set up a project on a Pi zero that runs a basic python script on startup. I made a last minute change and it passed the first few hurdles of a rudimentary test so I unplugged it and packed it in my bags. But now that I’m away from home, it looks like it’s running into a looping issue in the script.
I only SSH into it on my home network and I disabled the hdmi connection to reduce power consumption. So I can’t plug it in.
I added my phone’s existing hotspot details just in case, but of course I didn’t test that either. It doesn’t seem to work. I also changed the name of my phone to match my home network and matches the same passphrase, but no go.
Is there a way to SSH into this? I have a MacBook (Sonoma) and an iPhone. Any ideas?

Probably easiest to get an sd card reader and then use your macbook (possibly with a linux vm) to edit things. I like to always enable a serial console when configuring a Pi and then keep a usb ttl adapter handy for console access.
